# Неправильно настроен .htaccess $_GET получается пустым

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Я написал вот такой конфиг для htacces

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Он убирает последний слеш и перенаправляет с / на /index.php.

Я пытаюсь убрать расширение .php для файлов, чтобы остался только редирект на /index, но никак не получается.
Еще я пытаюсь научить свой apache отдавать всю статику, которая лежит в моей папке web/

Написал вот такое правило: `RewriteRule ^web/.+\.(jpg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ - [L]` но файлы с путем типа http://dummyadmin/web/css/main.css все равно возвращаются с ошибкой 404.

Как правильно настроить htacces чтобы редирект был на файл без .php и чтобы статика отдавалась из всех подпапок папки web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так, если я верно понял требования:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options -MultiViews

# Если запрос содержит в конце слеш или расширение .php, то
# делает редирект без них. Но только для тех запросов, которым 
# не соотествуют на ФС файл, папка или ссылка  ---> 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)(\.php|/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1 [L,R=301]
# <---

# Запросы, для которых нет на ФС папки, файла или ссылки, переписываем 
# в запрос к index.php, с оригинальным request_uri в качестве аргумента 
# параметра url --->
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
# <---
```

Для "статики" никаких дополнительных правил здесь не нужно, т.к. в пример правила срабатывают только для запросов, для которых нет в локальной ФС соответствия  скрипту (файлу/папки/ссылки).

Comment: Почему то теперь при обращении к http://dummyadmin/ он редиректит не на http://dummyadmin/index а просто на http://dummyadmin/ ... подскажите пожалуйста, почему тогда вся статика возвращается с ошибкой `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` ?

Comment: При запросе к http://dummyadmin зачем его редиректить на  http://dummyadmin/index -> index.php?url=index ??? Ведь запрос и так обрабатываться будет index.php без доп. редиректов.

Comment: пример url статики приведите, на который ответ 404

Comment: Если, например, файл /web/css/main.css существует, то правила, данные в ответе, не будут изменять запрос к нему

Comment: У меня в корне есть директория web, в ней папка css, в этой папке main.css. Я пытаюсь получить доступ к этой папке из файла, который находится в папке app->views->pages->home.php. Подключаю вот так `href="/web/css/main.css"` В консоль получаю `GET http://dummyadmin/web/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: а если в браузере набрать http://dummyadmin/web/css/main.css ?

Comment: Та же ошибка... я просто прочел где то, что нужно создать свой сервер или вроде того, чтобы статика отдавалась корректно, но не могу понять, как это сделать и нужно ли вообще это делать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100693/discussion-between-jigius-and--).